# cannot be serialized because it does not have a default public constructor

Tags: c#, xcode

It looks like an error occurred while serializing xml. Does anyone know the solution?

This is a system for obtaining information on xml data on the server.
An error occurs during communication from the client to the server.
The server system was created at visualstudio 2012. I created it.
An error occurs during data acquisition with xcode debugging

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace DEngine.Common.Services
{
    public class WorldInfo
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int Id;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string ServiceAddress;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public int Version;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string GameDB;
    }

    [XmlRoot("WorldList")]
    public class WorldInfoList
    {
        [XmlElement("World")]
        public List<WorldInfo> Worlds;



        public WorldInfoList()
        {
            Worlds = new List<WorldInfo>();
        }

        public static WorldInfoList FromXML(string xmlText)
        {
            using (StringReader strReader = new StringReader(xmlText))
            {
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WorldInfoList));
                WorldInfoList sheet = (WorldInfoList)xs.Deserialize(strReader);
                return sheet;
            }
        }



        public string ToXML()
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WorldInfoList));
            XmlSerializerNamespaces xn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            xn.Add("", "");

            using (StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                xs.Serialize(strWriter, this, xn);
                return strWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

error is delow

> InvalidOperationException: DEngine.Common.Services.WorldInfoList
>   cannot be serialized because it does not have a default public
>   constructor
>
> at ActiveAnimation.Finish () [0x00000] in :0
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.ReflectionHelper.CheckSerializableType
>   (System.Type type, Boolean allowPrivateConstructors) [0x00000] in
>   :0
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace) [0x00000] in :0
>
> Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting
>   type 'DEngine.Common.Services.WorldInfoList'.

Comment: This is definitely not C. I'm pretty sure this is C#, but I could be wrong. Feel free to fix it.

Comment: It is *very* unlikely code posted actually causes the error. Please double-check that you've provided [MCVE]. Also clean and rebuild all the code you have to verify that error is not caused by stale binaries.

Comment: Can you add the data test the you were using because I tested your code and is working perfect